# SQL query to display names of customers who have purchased some particular products

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

These are the tables I have created and inserted the values accordingly:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
     Customer_Id INTEGER IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     Customer_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Product
(
     Product_Id INTEGER IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     Product_Name VARCHAR(30)
)

CREATE TABLE Product_Purchase
(
     Purchase_Id INTEGER IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     Product_Id INTEGER NOT NULL,
     Customer_Id INTEGER NOT NULL
 )

INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_Name)
VALUES ('Sandip'), ('Ankit'), ('Ashok'), ('Raj')

INSERT INTO Product (Product_Name)
VALUES ('Milk'), ('Egg'), ('Butter'), ('Paneer'), ('Curd')

INSERT INTO Product_Purchase (Product_Id, Customer_Id)
VALUES (4, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1)
       (4, 2), (1, 2), 
       (4, 3), (3, 3), (1, 3),
       (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4)
```

So I have 3 tables Customers, Product and Product_Purchase with values inserted.

Now I want the list of customers who purchased only (Milk, Butter, and Paneer).

[All purchased items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MR3A.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of customers who purchased exactly (Milk, Butter, and Paneer) :

```
select cu.Customer_Name
 from Customer as cu inner join dbo.Product_Purchase as pu
 on pu.Customer_Id =cu.Customer_Id 
 where cu.Customer_Id not in 
 (select distinct pu.Customer_id  from  dbo.Product as pr inner join dbo.Product_Purchase as pu on pr.Product_Id=pu.Product_Id where Product_Name not in ('Milk', 'Butter','Paneer'))
 group by  cu.Customer_Name
 having count(pu.Product_id)=3
```

Comment: Hey @Mohammad Thanks for the answer but This is showing all the customer who purchased any of (Milk, Butter, and Paneer). But I want the list of customers who purchased exactly (Milk, Butter, and Paneer). For example: In this scenario Sandip(Id-1) and Ashok(Id-3) purchased exactly (Milk, Butter, and Paneer).

Comment: It is also showing the customer who purchased other products with Milk, Butter, and Paneer

Comment: Please see the snip https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MR3A.png The shaded rows should be the result

Comment: Thanks Man for working on this problem..... you are very close! Now,This is showing the list of customers who purchased one of (Milk, Butter, and Paneer) and product count = 3. For example it is showing the customer who purchased (Butter, Curd and Paneer) as well.

Comment: @OmVeer because based your data i got what you want in output

Comment: Yes  this is only sample data. But Query should be generalized not sample data specific. Right

Comment: i know , i just said based your data it was working so i updated my question , i will add more data to tables to see what is wrong with this query

Comment: Just add one row 
INSERT INTO Product_Purchase (Product_Id, Customer_Id)
VALUES (2, 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer_name
from Customer C, Product_Purchase PP, Product P
where C.Customer_Id = PP.Customer_Id
and   PP.Product_Id = P.Product_Id
and   Product_name in ('Milk', 'Butter', 'Paneer');
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer but
This is showing all the customer who purchased any of (Milk, Butter, and Paneer). But I want the list of customers who purchased exactly (Milk, Butter, and Paneer). For example: In this scenario Sandip(Id-1) and Ashok(Id-3) purchased exactly (Milk, Butter, and Paneer).

Comment: Yes Om Veer I see the problem now. You said it clearly: AND. Sorry, I have no simple solution.